# Why does AWS managed Apache Flink is stuck in version 1.15.2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink

Why does AWS don't update their managed Flink cluster to the most updated Flink version?

Is there a timeline for upgrade and if not, does it mean they don't see it as an attractive service?

Is there any other managed cluster (not a managed service like Ververica) that aligns with Apache Flink's roadmap?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-flink/latest/java/flink-1-15-2.html

I tried connecting AWS but got no reply

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for Decodable.*

> Is there any other managed cluster (not a managed service like Ververica) that aligns with Apache Flink's roadmap?

Decodable offer a managed Flink service in which you can run your own jobs (custom pipelines). We currently offer Flink 1.16.3 and 1.18.1. For more info see the [docs here](https://docs.decodable.co/docs/create-pipelines-using-your-own-apache-flink-jobs).

I think Aiven offer [something similar](https://aiven.io/docs/products/flink/howto/create-flink-applications). Confluent have a Flink offering but I don't know if it includes custom JARs.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Ververica

Can you share some more context on what - not a managed service like Ververica means?

I suspect you mean a cloud offering? In which case it has and you can try out for free:

https://www.ververica.com/cloud

Soon it will also be available in AWS, Azure and GC marketplaces.

If you look for a product/vendor - Ververica is definitely the most mature and feature-rich at the moment. And also supports the most recent Flink versions (1.18 is still WIP because it needs to verify stability first).

Also most of the Flink roadmap is driven by Ververica as it has most of the committers and grows the project for years now.